# How could an exploited application inject harmfull code?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, exploit

In theory this is pretty simple, just know the buffer size, or a memory address where the processor will be executing and write instructions to execute the code at the end of the filled buffer or from the mentioned address on.

But when ever I had a C program acting with that behavior on accident on my own system. The OS just terminated the application. So how could it even be possible to inject code, without forcing the OS to terminate the process?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention

Comment: I think this helps :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739349/understanding-and-doing-code-injection-in-c

Comment: @RemusRusanu Thanks for the article, looks quite itneressting, but on the first look, this looks to me not as an answer of how it would work, more it looks like a article of a technique of preventing this.

Comment: Modern OSes and hardwares implement DEP specifically to combat this issue. This is why your attempts probably did not work.

Comment: It were no attempts to. I just asked my self, as on the one hand the MSVC compiler warns me in so many cases about isnecure stuff which could cause a code inejection, and on the other hand, In now almost 3 years I'm coding each day, and never ever had a overflow that was not catched by the OS. So I'm just confused why they do such a big thing with it, if the OS'es have a prevention mehtod for it, anway.

Comment: A buffer overflow with random data will typically crash the application, as you say. Explicit buffer exploits are carefully crafted to do some useful function (in the eyes of the hacker) rather than crash.